# background picture of header does not take full width when you shrink the browser

Tags: html, css, responsive

I am making a header component and what I want to achieve is to make my header picture stretch to the full width of the webpage, even when it the browser shrinks, however when you shrink the browser the picture does not stretch 100% and is driving me insane. I don't want to remove the `scroll-x` property, so how can I fix this? What am I doing wrong? Here is is a picture of my issue:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9wAR.jpg

And here is a codepen with my code:
https://jsfiddle.net/philipkovachev9/ax2Ljtvn/5/

Comment: Hard problem I agree.. the problem is that the parent div has 100%. As its overflow-x, the body will only have the width of the window, not the overflow. If you use overflow-x: hidden; it would be fixed. But there should be another option. I need to figure it out

Comment: Yes, there surely must be another way, if you manage to figure it out I would be very grateful :)

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, within your question, and never any third party site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as promised I found a solution.

Change `display:flex` from your parent div, to `display: inline-block` and remove `width:100%`. You div will have the size of your content, even when it overflows.

Setting the width to 100% will be relative to the parent, it was the body. However, the body didn't include the overflow.

I hope it works :)

PS: If you still need `display:flex`, create a child div, with flex attribute.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

add this css

```
body{padding:0;margin:0}
```